# URL Button with Messenger Extensions always redirect to fallback_url

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Working on a **facebook messenger chatbot**, I try to use **[Webview and Extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-extension)** to display enhanced content *(in my case, a datepicker)*.

As describe in documentation, I send a **URL Button with Messenger Extensions** message, with a `fallback_url` to handle browser users.

```
{
   'type': 'web_url',
   'url':'https://abcdef.localtunnel.me/html/chatbotDatepicker.html',
   'title': 'Pick a date',
   'webview_height_ratio': 'tall',
   'messenger_extensions': true,
   'fallback_url': 'https://abcdef.localtunnel.me/html/chatbotError.html'
}
```

On my Android phone, everytime I click on that button, it properly open my webview but always and only using the `fallback_url`. If I remove the `fallback_url` it will use `url` as expected but then Facebook Javascript SDK only trigger errors 2071011 (like this one [Messenger Extensions Javascript SDK Error 2071011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490441/messenger-extensions-javascript-sdk-error-2071011/40674002)).

I feel like **messenger_extensions** might be disable, but I couldn't find any reference in documentation about enabling or disabling it.
May be this is related to the fact my application is public (has been reviewed by facebook), but I don't think so.

Does anyone ever had a similar problem, and know how to fix this ?! Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a valid bug and facebook team is working on it.Here is link to that https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1676913532599603/

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot for your reply, that bug was driving me crazy you made my day. Never saw this bug section, I'll definitely use it for now and keep an eye on it . Have a wonderfull day.